# Where two or more values match condition?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have been asked this question;

You list county names and the surnames of the representatives if the representatives in the counties have the same surname.

and I have the following tables;

```
***REPRESENTATIVE***
REPI SURNAME    FIRSTNAME  COUNTY     CONS
---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----
R100 Gorege     Larry      kent       CON1
R101 shneebly   john       kent       CON2
R102 shneebly   steve      kent       CON3
```

I cant seem to figure out the correct way to ask Orical to display a surname that exists more then twice and the surnames are in the same country.

I know how to ask WHERE something = something, but that's doesn't ask what I want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the `HAVING` clause after doing a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT surname, county, count(*)
  FROM you_table
 GROUP BY surname, county
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

If you really mean "more than twice" as you wrote, none of the data you'd want `HAVING count(*) > 2` but then none of your sample data would be returned.

In words, this SQL statement says

- Group the data into buckets by surname and county.  Each distinct combination of surname and county is a separate bucket.
- Count the number of rows in each bucket
- Return those buckets where there are at least two rows

Comment: ahh yes great :D, I tried something like that I'm reading through Database Systems by Thomas Connolly but I don't really understand this book. Can you explain the syntax to me a little more

Comment: Like what does Count(*) count everything ?